# Duda con JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, jupyter, machine-learning

queria saber como puedo guardar una vez terminado el modelo, en jupiter en un .sav ya que uso este comando y no me lo toma.

```
import pickle
filename = 'Mayo 2021 New Clusters.sav'
pickle.dump(tuned_model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

y ademas de como puedo cargar los datos de un .model ya que los guardo asi, al darme siempre error el .sav al guardarlos

Aqui detallo mas el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es al abrir noal guardar

Comment: es tanto para abrir como para guardar

Comment: has puesto la etiqueta de maching learning y tienes una variable llamada modelo. ¿Estas trabajando con algún modulo de deep learning como tensorflow, keras, pytorch?